# How to call Office 365 API from Web API?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I have an SPA based application, in which the UI uses Azure AD based authentication, in which the user is presented with a login page by Azure AD and the user logs in to get a token. I am getting the token successfully. Now the UI will call a Web API. This Web API needs to make a call to Office 365 API. I have office 365 tenant and the credentials (User2) are different from the credential the user is used to login from the UI. In this case how should I authenticate User2 to connect to Office 356 API and how should I pass the token to O365 API?

I googled for any sample but I could not find anything worth.

Comment: Can you clarify here: App A calls App B with User 1's identity. Then App B calls Office365 with Users 2's identity? Where is User 2 coming from. This doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I access the office 365 tenant using a different user "User 2".  This means that "User 1" does not have access to office 365 tenant.

Comment: This scenario just does not make sense. How does User 2 start becoming part of the process? If User 1 does not have access to Office 365, what are you trying to do?

Comment: As mentioned in my original question, I am trying to create a SPA application in which, users in my org. will authenticate themselves against Azure AD for Accessing Web API.  These users have no access to Office 365. This is the reason I have User 2 which has exclusive access to Office 365 tenant. I hope it is clear?